# Spring WebMVC 5 - Annotation based Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

How to configure an Interceptor, through Annotation only(I do NOT like to register the interceptor in .XML file, I do not use .XML based configuration)?

**Note : I see in example on internet it is suggesting to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, when I tried to use it, I found it is DEPRECATED**

I am testing on SpringWebMVC-5 with SpringBoot-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring5 you can use **org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer**:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
          registry.addInterceptor(....);
     }
 }
```

Comment: That comment is a different question, please ask it as such.

Comment: If using spring boot just take out the @EnableWebMvc